# What am I doing wrong with airdrop function?

Tags: contract-development

I am trying to move some tokens from my erc20 token to my second account. I am using myetherwallet to test this:

ERC20Interface has transfer function only.

```
    ERC20Interface token;
    constructor(address _token) public {
        token = ERC20Interface(_token);
    }
```

As I understand I pass contract token address through constructor which is here:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x8966504a3b07e2cecd4f4bbb3d51566c7127b156

I then use function(i am doing transactions with an account which was initially assigned tokens so I have erc20 tokens):

```
function drop(address[] recipients, uint256[] values) public {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < recipients.length; i++) {
        token.transfer(recipients[i], values[i]);

        emit DropedFun(address(this), recipients[i], values[i]);
    }
}
```

I am getting failed transaction:
https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x4dcb95d87feed1f62cd50fe3921b5683878f718bc17dddf0150b9ba1a94e3059

Do I have to use transferFrom and put address which holds erc20 tokens, or should i transfer erc20 token to the address to be able to use .transfer function? If that's the case, how can I transfer erc20 token to contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contract you are using to disperse airdrops needs to have a balance of tokens in oder to use the `transfer` function. To do so send tokens to the contract. Do note though that if you don't program in a method to withdraw tokens, it is possible for them to get stuck in the contract.

If you want to use the `transferFrom` function, you need to make sure to give an appropriate `allowance`.

Some links for reading:

- [How Ethereum token transfer works](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/26284/how-ethereum-token-transfer-works)
- https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/ERC20_Token_Standard#How_Does_A_Token_Contract_Work.3F

Comment: Sure but how to transfer erc20 token into smart contract? And as you can see I tried to not transfer erc20 by invoking drop with my own account which has all the erc20 tokens but it still failed.

Comment: If you have the tokens in your wallet, sending them to the contract address of the airdrop contract would be fine.

Comment: That’s exactly what I am doing in mentioned function and still getting fail transaction. Regarding erc20 does that mean I can send token via new to contract and it should work like eth payable function? Any example of implementation?

Comment: No, you have to send tokens to the contract *first*. The contract you link doesn't have any tokens that are being held by it. Send tokens to it first and then what you are doing will work. It's no different than sending tokens normally,  instead just make sure to send it to the contract.

Comment: I forgot you can actually send tokens to contract like to normal address. You just need empty payable function I guess.

Comment: No, you only need the empty payable function to send ether, tokens you don't need that. However tokens can get trapped in contracts because by default they don't have the ability to send or interact with tokens.

Comment: I see yeah makes sense